# D3 add more than one functions to an eventlistener

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom-events

I am trying to add more than one functions to one eventlistner. 
But it does not work. When I click on, it won't trigger the stop function.

**So my question is, isn't it possible to give an event more than one function? Or is there another problem?**

```
<svg>
<g id="graph">
    <circle cx="16.887" cy="333.923" r="6.268"/>
    <circle cx="33.574" cy="333.923" r="6.268"/>
    <circle cx="50.262" cy="333.923" r="6.268"/>
    <circle cx="66.949" cy="333.923" r="6.268"/>
    <circle cx="167.074" cy="333.923" r="6.268"/>
    <circle cx="183.762" cy="333.923" r="6.268"/>
    <circle cx="333.387" cy="333.923" r="6.268"/>
    <circle cx="316.699" cy="333.923" r="6.268"/>
    <circle cx="300.199" cy="334.101" r="6.268"/>
    <circle cx="266.637" cy="333.923" r="6.268"/>
    <circle class="grey" cx="250.137" cy="333.923" r="6.268"/>
    <circle class="grey" cx="216.762" cy="333.923" r="6.268"/>
</g>
</svg>

<script>
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var g = svg.select("#graph");

/*[--- Give every circle/event the function stop ---]*/
g.selectAll("circle").on('mouseover',stop);
g.selectAll("circle").on('mouseout',stop);

/* [---------- mouseover and mouseout hover effect ----------]*/
svg.selectAll("circle")
.on('mouseover', function(d){
   d3.select(this)
   .transition()
   .attr ({"r": "10"})
   .style("fill", "black")
})

 .on('mouseout', function(d){
    d3.select(this)
    .transition()
    .delay(100)
    .attr ({"r": "6.268"})
    .style("fill", "#7F4292")
 })

 svg.selectAll(".grey")
 .on('mouseout', function(d){
    d3.select(this)
    .transition()
    .delay(100)
    .attr ({"r": "6.268"})
    .style("fill", "#A9A9A9")
 })
 /* [----------------------------------------------]*/


 /* [--------------- stop loop Function ----------------]*/
 function stop() {
    if(run) {
      run = false;
    }
    else {
      run = true;
    }
 }
```

There is a further function which enlarges the circles random, but for my question it does not matter.

Comment: I recommend reading the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#on) --> `If an event listener was already registered for the same type on the selected element, the existing listener is removed before the new listener is added. To register multiple listeners for the same event type...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay cool. 
it works when I add *.foo*.

If an event listener was already registered for the same type on the selected element, the existing listener is removed before the new listener is added. **To register multiple listeners for the same event type, the type may be followed by an optional namespace, such as "click.foo" and "click.bar".** The first part of the type ("click" for example) is used to register the event listener (using element.addEventListener()) and methods are added on the selected elements as __onclick.foo and __onclick.bar.

```
    /*[--- Give every circle/event the function stop ---]*/
    g.selectAll("circle").on('mouseover.foo',stop);
    g.selectAll("circle").on('mouseout.foo',stop);
```